Send custom html with OTP code using sendgrid with Custom policy results in error msg in console log
I'm trying to send an OTP code via sendgrid as part of MFA. I followed these steps described here.
But when I navigate to localhost:3000 to test the OTP, trying to login with my credentials. Nothing happens, but when I look in my console log, I see this error:

Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'self' 'nonce-c7cJJBRlOHvhhttGtKagEg==' 'report-sample'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

And when I click on the file name authorize, I can see its pointing to the first line in that document where the error occurs.
See this screenshot:

I'm building a vue/nuxt (version 3+) as the front-end and ASP.NET Core MVC as the backend. I can send the email using postman, but not when I use my tech stack.
I have been look for a solution now for almost a week. I was wondering if someone else run into this issue?

AFAIK The error message indicates that the inline JavaScript execution is being blocked due to the CSP settings. You may need to adjust your Content Security Policy to allow inline scripts. This can be done by adding 'unsafe-inline' to your script-src directive, but be cautious as this can introduce security risks.

I tried that but didn't work, maybe i added it in the wrong place. Where exactly should i add this? I tried adding this both in back end and front-end.

Ensure the CSP header is added before your MVC or routing middleware in your Startup.cs and update your nuxt.config.js to include the CSP in the head section

@Rukmini didnt work. What else can I try?

Instead of using 'unsafe-inline', try using nonce-based CSP. This involves generating a nonce fot each request and including it in both the CSP and the inline script tags.
Generate a nonce in your backend when rendering the page.
Add the nonce to your CSP header.

This CSP error comes from the login page from azure itself. The screenshot is from that page. And I don't think i have any control on that page. AFAIK there is no way of injecting CSP in that html login page... Could the error come from misconfiguration in my xml files containing the custom policies?

Yes it might be the issue

Okay, can you share your xml files so I can compare them with mine? Make sure you remove sensitive information out of it first.
